# The popup should come after we hover on the 3 dots, but in my case the popup is there permanantly which obstructs the ui

Tags: reactjs, antd

This window which is circled it doesn't go away it stays there untill I delete tabs. Help

[image: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXxMr.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXxMr.png)]

Following is the code I've writter:

```js
export default function Tool() {
  const [tabId, setTabId] = useState(1);
  const [tabArray, setTabArray] = useState([]);
  const [activeKey, setActiveKey] = useState("1");
  useEffect(() => {
    const tempTabArray = [...tabArray, tabId];
    setTabArray(tempTabArray);
  }, []);

  const addTab = () => {
    const tempTabId = tabId + 1;
    setTabId(tempTabId);
    const tempTabArray = [...tabArray, tempTabId];
    setTabArray(tempTabArray);
  };

  const removeTab = (targetKey) => {
    const tempArray = tabArray.filter((id) => id !== targetKey);

    setTabArray(tempArray);
  };

  const onChange = (newActiveKey) => {
    setActiveKey(newActiveKey);
  };

  const onEdit = (targetKey, action) => {
    if (action === "add") {
      addTab();
    } else {
      removeTab(targetKey);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ConfigProvider
        theme={{
          components: {
            Tabs: {
              colorBgContainer: "#2f2f2f",
              colorPrimary: "White",
              colorText: "white",
            },
          },
        }}
      >
        <Tabs
          type="editable-card"
          className="bp3-dark config-tabs db-client-tabs"
          style={{ height: 220 }}
          onEdit={onEdit}
          defaultActiveKey={activeKey}
          onChange={onChange}
          items={tabArray.map((id) => {
            return {
              label: `Untitled Request`,
              key: id,
              children: <SingleTab />,
              closeIcon: <CloseOutlined className="custom-close-icon" />,
            };
          })}
        />
      </ConfigProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/discussions/42190

I read the documentation but no solution. I don't want that window it's covering the UI. If possibel I don't want that certain feature at not even the three dots.